# JavaScript function doesn't work as per JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am encoding my returned response through JSON and trying to make it work as per the JSON Response's values.

Assume below values are what I am returning.

```
if ($upload = 1){
    $response['status'] = 1;
    $response['message'] = 'SUCCESS';
    $response['success'] = 'false'; 
}else{
    $response['status'] = 3;
    $response['message'] = 'CATEGORY ASSOCIATED';
    $response['success'] = 'false'; 
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

I will be retrieving it to my form and handle the action through the encoded responses.

```
 $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: {cid:id},
        success: function(response){
            if(response.status = 1){
                console.log('THE STATUS IS 1');
            }
            else if(response.status = 3){
                console.log('THE STATUS IS 3');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The issue I am facing is I am getting both responses on browser's network tab. console prints status 1 but not status 3. Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: use `==` not `=` in the condition

Comment: look for a post that describes the difference between `=` (assignment), `==` (equality check) and `===` (strict equality check) ... hint `response.status = 1` is ALWAYS truthy

Comment: Strict check helped. Please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.....

```
 $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: {cid:id},
        success: function(response,status){
            if(status == 1){
                const newres = JSON.parse(response);//parse the response 
                if(newres.status == 1)
                console.log('The status is 1');
                else if (newres.status == 3) 
                console.log('The status is 3');
            }
            else {
                console.log('No response');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The `json_encode($response);` is a json format string, parsing makes it an object.

Comment: Please explain why would I consider making it an object when I can achieve the task using - if(response.status === 1){} as this.

Comment: can you explain me how you can achieve it with `if(response.status === 1)` as I know the json_encode will look like `{"status":1,"message":"SUCCESS","success":"false"}` [in your case] which is a json string format.

Comment: maybe json encode returns an INT and I am strictly looking for an INT using === in my JS. double operator skips it.

Comment: Ohh ok it's searching for the integer, I thought you want to access object members, anyways it can help accessing other 2 members.